# Creating Hive table - how to derive column names from CSV source?

Tags: mysql, csv, hadoop, hive, apache-spark

...I really thought this would be a well-traveled path.

I want to create the DDL statement in Hive (or SQL for that matter) by inspecting the first record in a CSV file that exposes (as is often the case) the column names.

I've seen a variety of near answers to this issue, but not to many that can be automated or replicated at scale.

I created the following code to handle the task, but I fear that it has some issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import csv

# get file name (and hence table name) from command line
# exit with usage if no suitable argument

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   sys.exit('Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ': input CSV filename')
ifile = sys.argv[1]

# emit the standard invocation
print 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ' + ifile + ' ('

with open(ifile + '.csv') as inputfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)
   for row in reader:
      k = row.keys()
      sprung = len(k)
      latch = 0
      for item in k:
         latch += 1
         dtype = '` STRING' if latch == sprung else '` STRING,'
         print '`' + item.strip() + dtype
      break
   print ')\n'

print "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
print "LOCATION 'replacethisstringwith HDFS or S3 location'"
```

The first is that it simply datatypes everything as a STRING.  (I suppose that coming from CSV, that's a forgivable sin. And of course one could doctor the resulting output to set the datatypes more accurately.)

The second is that it does not sanitize the potential column names for characters not allowed in Hive table column names. (I easily broke it immediately by reading in a data set where the column names routinely had an apostrophe as data. This caused a mess.)

The third is that the data location is tokenized. I suppose with just a little more coding time, it could be passed on the command line as an argument.

My question is -- why would we need to do this? What easy approach to doing this am I missing?

(BTW: no bonus points for referencing the CSV Serde - I think that's only available in Hive 14. A lot of us are not that far along yet with our production systems.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first issue (all columns are typed as strings), this is actually the current behavior even if the table were being processed by something like the CSVSerde or RegexSerDe.  Depending on whether the particulars of your use case can tolerate the additional runtime latency, one possible approach is to define a view based upon your external table that dynamically recasts the columns at query time, and direct queries against the view instead of the external table.  Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW my_view (
  CAST(col1 AS INT) AS col1,
  CAST(col2 AS STRING) AS col2,
  CAST(col3 AS INT) as col3,
  ...
  ...
) AS SELECT * FROM my_external_table;
```

For the second issue (sanitizing column names), I'm inferring your Hive installation is 0.12 or earlier (0.13 supports any unicode character in a column name).  If you import the `re` regex module, you can perform that scrubbing in your Python with something like the following:

```
for item in k:
  ...
  print '`' + re.sub(r'\W', '', item.strip()) + dtype
```

That should get rid of any non-alphernumeric/underscore characters, which was the pre-0.13 expectation for Hive column names.  By the way, I don't think you need the surrounding backticks anymore if you sanitize the column name this way.

As for the third issue (external table location), I think specifying the location as a command line parameter is a reasonable approach.  One alternative may be to add another "metarow" to your data file that specifies the location somehow, but that would be a pain if you are already sitting on a ton of data files - personally I prefer the command line approach.

Comment: Yes, I am (at the moment) working on a pre-0.13 release, but that will probably change this week.

Thanks for the regex phrase to scrub the column names. That's quite helpful, and would probably deserve to be a cmd-line flag option even in a post-0.13 world.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kite SDK](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.0.0/Using-the-Kite-CLI-to-Create-a-Dataset.html) has functionality to infer a CSV schema with the names from the header record and the types from the first few data records, and then create a Hive table from that schema. You can also use it to import CSV data into that table.

Comment: Thanks. Kite looks good. Seems that it's currently limited to Java, but that's not debilitating.  One thing though. All the doc I looked at pre-supposes using CDH. Is that the case, or is it just a natural presumption? I'm working with a Hive-as-a-Service offering (Qubole) and maybe this would integrate. I can't tell for sure. There's no "system requirements" statement that I could see.

Comment: I'm not sure about Qubole, but Kite has dependencies both for CDH specifically and Apache Hadoop generally, so there's a good chance. http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.0.0/dependencies/

Comment: Thanks, that does provide a helpful insight into how Kite is used, and where it might be useful.